# Cannot do positional indexing on RangeIndex with these indexers - numpy one-liner to get average of every 12th value in series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, slice

I'm trying to create a one-liner that fills na values in a pandas series with the average of every 12th previous value. I feel like this should work

```
test = pd.Series([10,5,3,4,6,12,6,7,2,4,7,12,6,7,2,4,7,12,3,4,6,12,6,7]+[pd.NA]*12)
test = pd.Series(np.where(test.isna(),test.iloc[test.index%12::12].mean(),test))
```

Because when I have the second part of the np.where() function use "test.index%12" it returns the number I want to use to slice the series with iloc, but I get an error running it as it is because test.index appears to be pulling the whole series representing the index of "test" - this is the error I get:

```
TypeError: cannot do positional indexing on RangeIndex with these indexers [Int64Index([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,
             5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,
            10, 11],
           dtype='int64')] of type Int64Index
```

How can I get iloc to slice the series as expected? Or if there is a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do please let me know

Comment: why do you expect that passing `RangeIndex::12` to `iloc` to work?

Comment: @RuggeroTurra when I put "test.index%12" in the second part of np.where() it returns a number. When I put it where it is it returns a rangeindex. I don't expect a rangeindex to work, I expect it not to return a rangeindex

Comment: but you are not passing a RangeIndex to `loc`. You are passing a slice, made by a `RangeIndex` and a number. I don't know what it would mean, but it is not supported. In the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html): "A slice object with ints, e.g. 1:7."

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a one liner solution. This is using the mean of the last 12 numbers, not sure it is what you meant by "the average of every 12th previous value"

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

test = pd.Series([10,5,3,4,6,12,6,7,2,4,7,12,6,7,2,4,7,12,3,4,6,12,6,7]+[np.nan]*12)

test.where(lambda x: ~np.isnan(x), test.rolling(12, min_periods=1).mean())
```

note that I have changed `pd.NA` with `np.nan`